# Need help with DNS and URLS for database attach upgrade to 2013 from 2010

Tags: 2010, 2013, upgrade

this is a basic question I guess. I am doing a upgrade from 2010 to 2013. I am just a bit unsure about the best way to set up a test server without end users being able to access it.
In the Microsoft planning docs, they said to setup the URLS and host headers before attaching the databases.
I figured that I should keep the 2013 server off DNS, but if I have the same URL's on the 2013 box as the 2010 box has, how can I keep people on the 2010 URL's until the 2013 server is ready?

Comment: When doing this scenario, I always use local HOST entries instead of DNS. That way I can access the sites at their new locations, but no one else can. Then later when you're ready, just switch DNS to make the live move.

Comment: This is perfect, I will go with this, since I am the only guy in the office that will be working on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per your question, i can give you what we did during the migration.

1. we created temp DNS/URL point to sharepoint 2013
2. Now setup the SharePoint 2013 with new temp urls.
3. migrate the data from 2010 to 2013(whatever method you use).
4. test the migration, everything looks good
5. Now Swap the URL, temp point to the 2010 and Old 2010 Points to 2013, for this you need to update the DNS pointing and also AAM setting in sharepoint.

so above method, you have your both environment up and in case reversal just swap the url back to original.If everything works then decommission the temp DNS and 2010 farm.

Comment: This is a good method and easy to understand, thank you!